# SQL sum pairs of values

Tags: sql, hive

I'm new to SQL and I couldn't figure how to do this. I would like to sum a coulmn called "total_spending" for similar pairs (vin, action) and choose the first dealer_name and reference month year (so it won't create duplicates) and have an output like the example:
Input

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T3             R2     M2    Y2
A3      D2            V1         T4             R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A1      D1            V1         T7             R2     M2    Y2
A4      D1            V2         T8             R2     M2    Y2
A1      D1            V1         T9             R3     M3    Y3
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T11            R2     M2    Y2
```

output

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2 + T3        R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T4 + T11       R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5 + T8        R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1


    SELECT
        action,
        dealer_name,
        vin,
        SUM(total_spending) as total_spending,
        reference,
        year,
        issue_date,
        country_code
    FROM
        db_raw_irn_67634_vdt.sap_vme_pol
    GROUP BY
        action,
        dealer_name,
        vin,
        reference,
        year,
        issue_date,
        country_code
```

Comment: Is total_spending column of a number  datatype? Also which is your RDBMS?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Total_spending is a double, RDBMS Distributed database ( Hadoop Hive ) , thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports window functions, you can do a window `SUM()` and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to select the relevant records to display:

```
SELECT 
    action,
    dealer_name,
    vin,
    total_spending,
    reference,
    month, 
    year
FROM (
    SELECT
        action,
        dealer_name,
        vin,
        SUM(total_spending) OVER(PARTITION BY action, dealer_name, vin) total_spending,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY action, dealer, vin ORDER BY reference, year, month) rn,
        reference,
        month, 
        year
    FROM mytable
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT action
    ,dealer_name
    ,vin
    ,SUM(total_spending)
    ,MIN(reference)
    ,MIN(month)
    ,MIN(YEAR)
FROM db_raw_irn_67634_vdt.sap_vme_pol
GROUP BY action
    ,dealer_name
    ,vin
```

Comment: This only works *if* the minimum reference, month and year belong to the same record.